# Qt SQLite database without absolute path

Tags: database, qt, sqlite, resources, absolute-path

Is there a way to reference the database.sqlite file without knowing the absolute path?

```
_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
_db.setDatabaseName("/the/path/i/dont/know/database.sqlite");
```

- I already tried to add the database.sqlite to the Resources folder and call it via `qrc:`, but apparently it is not possible to write to a resource file.
- I also tried using `QApplication::applicationDirPath();`, but this would result in different paths depending on the user's OS. E.g. it appends `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS` to the actual directory.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a QSqlDatabase with SQLite as a backend you have two options:

- Give an absolute path as a db name
- Give a relative path: in this case the database will be saved in the directory of your binary.

So you must know absolute path of your db in your case.

**edit**

In the case you initially know where the database should be located you can either hardcode it (which is never wise) or you can create a configuration and load it using QSettings. For example:

```
QSettings settings;
QString dbPath = settings.readValue("DBPath", QString(/*fallback path*/)).toString();
//do smth with dbPath
```

Take a look further [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsettings.html)

Comment: In my app for example I build up an absolute path from my configuration. We have a multiuser environment and depending on the username I build up a home directory and so on. What requirements do you have for your application?

Comment: Well basically I want to create a .sqlite DB on first startup and then use that DB whenever the user starts the app again. So nothing really fancy about that :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But does that change anything? I still can't just reference the path to database.sqlite, because it depends on the place it is executed and on the system it is executed on?

Comment: The path to the db does depends on the platform, so with sqlite in the end you have to decide on where you want to store the db

Comment: @alex how did you get it.Is it worked fine.Do you have any solution for get it.I have got issuse same you.:(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the db per user you shout use this:

```
QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation)
```

this method returns the location where persistent application data can be stored.

for more information check this: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation